# Unit tests are failing after adding environment variable to main file

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm currently using an environment variable to hide my API's key. My unit test that is testing the API route is now failing. However, when the key was hard-coded into the main file, the tests passed. Here is my code:

```
import os 
import requests

key = os.environ.get('key')

def test_code(state, API_BASE_URL):
    url = f'https://covid-19-testing.github.io/locations/{state.lower()}/complete.json'
    res = requests.get(url)
    testing_data = res.json()
    latsLngs = {}
    for obj in testing_data:
          if obj["physical_address"]:

            for o in obj["physical_address"]:
                    addy = o["address_1"] 
                    city = o["city"]
                    phone = obj["phones"][0]["number"]

            location = f'{addy} {city}'
            location_coordinates = requests.get(API_BASE_URL,
                                params={'key': key, 'location': location}).json()

            lat = location_coordinates["results"][0]["locations"][0]["latLng"]["lat"]
            lng = location_coordinates["results"][0]["locations"][0]["latLng"]["lng"]
            latsLngs[location] = {'lat': lat, 'lng': lng, 'place': location, 'phone': phone}
    return latsLngs
```

Here is the unit test:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from models import db, User
from sqlalchemy.exc import InvalidRequestError

class UserViewTestCase(TestCase):
    """Test views for users."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Create test client, add sample data."""
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        
        self.testuser = User.signup('test',
                            'dummy',
                            'test123',
                            'dummytest@test.com',
                            'password',
                            None,
                            "Texas",
                            None,
                            None)
        self.uid = 1111
        self.testuser.id = self.uid
        db.session.commit()


def test_map_locations(self):
        """Does the map show testing locations?"""
        with self.client as c:  
            resp = c.get('/location?state=California')
            html = resp.get_data(as_text=True)

            self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

            self.assertIn('San Francisco', html)
```

I also think it's important to note that the application runs fine in the browser. It's just that the unit tests are not passing anymore.

*UPDATE*

Here is the full traceback:

```
ERROR: test_map_locations (test_user_views.UserViewTestCase)
Does the map show testing locations?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/build/azaria-dedmon/covid-19/tests/test_user_views.py", line 157, in test_map_locations
    resp = c.get('/location?state=California')
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1006, in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 227, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 970, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 861, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/travis/build/azaria-dedmon/covid-19/app/__init__.py", line 111, in show_state_locations
    latsLngs = test_code(state, API_BASE_URL)
  File "/home/travis/build/azaria-dedmon/covid-19/app/refactor.py", line 22, in test_code
    params={'key': key, 'location': location}).json()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/python/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/python/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Where does your unit test create an environment variable named `key` containing the key needed by the test code? (And if it does, does it do so before the module calls `os.environ.get` to get the value of said variable?)

Comment: I've edited my code snippet to show how my application is using the key variable but I'll also show you here:  ```key = os.environ.get('key')```. I defined it inside of the test setup

Comment: The `key` variable in `setUp` (which you never subsequently use) has nothing to do with `key` used by the function `test_code`.

Comment: Can you show the actual error messages you're getting ?

Comment: I have updated my code to show the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most likely that your test framework is loading *just* the `test_code()` function from your test file, and not the fact that `key` is set up in the main body of the code. Perhaps moving your `key = os.environ.get("key")` into `test_code()` will solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable needs to be set in the project's repository in travis CI so that all files have access to it. Here is the documentation on how to achieve this https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-variables-in-repository-settings